# F.lux unattended installer

Tags: windows, f.lux

I'm looking to create an unattended installer for F.lux for Windows, but don't want users to be prompted by the initial location configuration.

Where are the settings for F.lux stored, so I can set the location before the installer is executed?

Comment: How can I use them to make an unattended installation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

F.lux settings are stored in the registry.

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Michael Herf\flux\Preferences
```